# NSButton with down-facing triangle on the right

Tags: macos, cocoa, geometry, nsbutton, accessory

I'm trying to make a native NSButton object in IB. When I select Accessory as a Button Type, the title disappears. When I try to write the title, the button is not resizing and the triangle keeps disappearing.

How to make a NSButton with text and down-facing accessory triangle on the right indicating this is something you can click and will popover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [NSPopUpButton](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPopUpButton_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: And, either in code or in the IB attributes inspector, change the type to "pull down" (the default is "pop up").